# Unique Usernames Prevented Due To Firebase Rules

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

So in my current iOS app I am utilizing firebase and I am currently trying to make it so all users have unique usernames at the sign up stage. This function that I have seems to do the trick of checking if the username exists or not.

```
//will ensure that a user has a unique username
static func checkUserNameAlreadyExist(newUserName: String, completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: newUserName)
        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                completion(true)
            }
            else {
                completion(false)
            }
        })
}
```

However, when I try to run this function on creation of a user in my signup screen. It doesn't do it and gives this error

```
Listener at /users failed: permission_denied
```

I reached the conclusion that it has to do with my rules which are currently the default.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    ".indexOn": "g"
  }
}
```

So my question is...Is there anyway I can change my rules to work with this function because I don't want to authenticate a user before I check if the username is unique. That could potentially add thousands of people to the auth in the event that many usernames are taken.Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have many potential solutions here.  Here are some off the top of my head:

1. You could allow anybody to read your `users` document.  If there is nothing sensitive in there it might make sense to allow this, though you are probably right in requiring that the user is at least authenticated.

This solution would look like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "auth != null"
    }
  }
}
```

2. Are users signing in with email or Facebook or something?  If so, you could let them authenticate, and then after they are authenticated you ask them to pick a username, at which point they are allowed to query the `users` document for valid usernames.

There is no need for sample code here, as if you waited for the user to authenticate before calling the function in your question the function would be working at that point.  Then you'd just need to update the `username` key on that user in your `users` document.

3. You could maintain a separate document tracking used usernames, and make that document readable by all.  That way unauthenticated users can check their username, but they don't have access to any other portion of your Firebase database.

To do this one, you'd have to create a new document (let's call it `usernames`), and every time a user successfully authenticates you add them to the `user` document, and add their username to the `username` document.  Then you'd set your permission for `usernames` like in my first example:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "usernames": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "auth != null"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: okay so what would an actual solution look like. Im also not signing in with facebook and if I authenticate them they will be add under my auth tab which i Kind've dont want

Comment: Oof, so you're skipping Authentication completely and just manually implementing your own authentication methods and functionality from scratch?

Comment: Also, if you're not using Firebase's built-in Authentication your database rules will block 100% of users from reading or writing since "auth != null" will always be false.

Comment: I am using firebase auth

Comment: hey solution 1 seems to block everything else. should i be adding another rule for differnet access.

Comment: Yes, for sure.  That snippet is just showing how to handle access for `users`.  You'll need to set rules for everything else as well.  Check the examples in the docs.